# Script keeps "running in circles"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Building FAQ widget and got stuck at minimizing current question. Question switch is working fine. But when I try to just minimize currently open question, it starts" running in loops ('i'm guessing). Because, when I add an alert after code, it behaves the way it's supposed to, but after alert is closed, it's back to it's original state

HTML of it

```
<div class="faqttlitem faqttlitem3">
     <div class="acfaqttl acfaqttl3">Question</div>
        <div class="mobfaqcont  mobfaqcont3">
           <div class="mobfaqaccontimg mobfaqaccontimg3 w100">
              <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0213/3764/t/38/assets/faq_img3.jpg?6062394605562480157"></div>
           <div class="mobfaqacconttxt mobfaqacconttxt3">answer text here</div>
         </div>
 </div>
```

and the JS

```
if ($(window).width()< 801 ){

  $(".faqttlitem").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){

      if ( $(this).hasClass('activefaq') ) {

        $(this).removeClass('activefaq');
        $(this).find('.mobfaqcont').hide();
        //alert('wtf'); doesn't work without it

      } else {

       $(this).parent().find(".activefaq").removeClass("activefaq");
       $(this).parent().find(".activefaq").find(".mobfaqcont").hide();
      $(this).addClass('activefaq');
      $(this).find(".mobfaqcont").show();
      }


    });
  });


  } else {}
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ncxqjfqg/

Comment: also remove the dot from removeClass, you only need to pass the name here $(this).parent().find(".activefaq").removeClass(".activefaq");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to work fine.

But just in case because your each function is kinda unnecessary. If you do an on function into a jQuery element, he binds the function to each element, and the this is different in each one, so for performance issues do the following changes :

```
if ($(window).width() < 801) {

$(".faqttlitem").on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('activefaq')) {
            $(this).removeClass('activefaq');
            $(this).find('.mobfaqcont').hide();
        } else {
            $(this).parent().find(".activefaq").removeClass("activefaq");
            $(this).parent().find(".activefaq").find(".mobfaqcont").hide();
            $(this).addClass('activefaq');
            $(this).find(".mobfaqcont").show();
        }

});
} else {}
```